# Malicious link added to website in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So I have a wordpress website that has a malicious link being added in the navigation of my site but when I log in it disappears and I can find no trace of it in the code at all. I am wondering if anyone has had this issue before and how they took care of it.

Comment: How did you understand it was malicious?

Comment: What exactly is the link?

Comment: The link is sexy homemade movie and goes to 404 page on a car website

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is change to the default twentyfifteen or twentyfourteen theme and disable all plugins and see if the link is still there. If it's not, reactivate your theme and see if the link returns. If it does, it's from  the theme; the theme is either hacked (see below) or it's a free (or junk) theme and the author added the link.

If the theme is not adding the link, reactivate plugins one at a time to see which one may be adding the link.

Depending on above: this sounds like you got hacked. Time to fix it right the first time, or you will get hacked again. You need to replace all core WP files/folders (except wp-config.php and wp-content), but scan the uploads folder and theme for exploit code and modified files or added files, comparing to a copy of your original theme. Replace all plugins, too.

Also scan the database for `eval` code and added administrators. (See "My Site was Hacked" below).

Change all host, FTP and WordPress passwords in the process. Scan your own PC for malware that might have grabbed logins and passwords.

Tell your web host you got hacked; and consider changing to a more secure host.

Carefully follow [FAQ - My Site Was Hacked](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) at WordPress.org.

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks) at WordPress.org.

Comment: cool thanks for the advice. I was wondering if you could explain why the link disappears when I log in?

Comment: No idea; could be the theme authors' failed effort to hide the link from the site admins.

Comment: interesting well I thank you for your help and hopefully I can get this taken care of